# How to make smallest value is not equal to 0?

Tags: c++

I want to get the highest and smallest value from the data. For the highest I managed to get it. but for the smallest, the value is always 0. I have tried many ways but didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string input;
ifstream nameFile("data.txt");

if (!nameFile)
    return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1;

while (getline(nameFile, input))
        cout << input << endl;

nameFile.clear();
nameFile.seekg(0);

int largest_1 {} , smallest_1 {};
int largest_2 {} , smallest_2 {};
int largest_3 {} , smallest_3 {};

for (int a {}, b {}, c {}, d {}, e {}; nameFile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e; )
{
    if (c > largest_1)
        largest_1 = c;

    if (d > largest_2)
        largest_2 = d;

    if (e > largest_3)
        largest_3 = e;

    if (c < smallest_1)
        smallest_1 = c;

    if (d < smallest_2)
        smallest_2 = d;

    if (e < smallest_3)
        smallest_3 = e;
}


std::cout << "The largest value 1 is " << largest_1 << '\n';
std::cout << "The largest value 2 is " << largest_2 << '\n';
std::cout << "The largest value 3 is " << largest_3 << '\n';

std::cout << "The smallest value 1 is " << smallest_1 << '\n';
std::cout << "The smallest value 2 is " << smallest_2 << '\n';
std::cout << "The smallest value 3 is " << smallest_3 << '\n';
}
```

There is no value of 0 in the data.txt, however I got 0 for my smallest value answer. How to fix it?

Comment: bracket initialization `smallest_1 {};` is initializing `smallest_1` to `0`. Set it to max value of `int` instead. Set the largest values to min value of `int` while you're at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no value of 0 in the data.txt, however I got 0 for my smallest value answer.

This is because you initiailse `smallest_X` to zero, and then assign a read value only if it is smaller. Thus, if the content has no value smaller than 0, then `smallest_X` will remain as 0.

One approach is to assign them unconditionally after first read:

```
int a, b, c, d, e;
nameFile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

int largest_1 = c , smallest_1 = c;
int largest_2 = d , smallest_2 = d;
int largest_3 = e , smallest_3 = e;

for (; nameFile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e; )
{
   ///
```